# wall.getReposts method of VK.com API isn't working correctly

Tags: api, vk

{response}->{profiles} returns only array of users that did repost with addition, not all.

E.g. for this [post](https://vk.com/wood_staff?w=shares/wall-104622889_69) (owner_id = -104622889, post_id = 69) it returns about 5 items, in fact there are more than 70 reposts.

Such behaviour isn't mentioned in [official documentation](https://vk.com/dev/wall.getReposts). Is it a bug or feature? And how to fetch all reposts?

Comment: Paul! It's a bug. Support does not answer when will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Paul! New answer :) Use method `likes.getList` with parameter `filter=copies` and you will receive an array of `user_id` who've made a repost! It works, I've checked twice.

https://vk.com/dev/likes.getList